# Differential equation - Graphic solution and limits

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

You have the following differential equation:

$\frac{\text{d}N}{\text{d}t}=0,00029N*(1500-N) \\ N(0)=200$

a) For what $t$ is $N \geq 750$?

I have no idea how to solve this differential equation. Is it even of the first order? Because those are the only ones I know how to solve algebraically. Is there a way of solving it on my graph calculator?

b) What is the value of $lim_{t \rightarrow 8}N(t)$?

My thought is that $N \rightarrow 1500$ when $t \rightarrow 8$, but how do I show it? Is it even correct? If not, how to solve the question?

Comment: This equation is separable. Do $\frac{\text{d}N}{0,00029N*(1500-N) }=\text{d}t$ and integrate. About your calculator, is that an assignment? Why would you want to graph this on a calculator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{\text{d}N}{\text{d}t}=0,00029N*(1500-N)\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$dN=\left(0,00029N*(1500-N)\right)dt\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$dN=(0.435N-0.00029N^2)dt\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\frac{1}{0.435N-0.00029N^2}dN=dt\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\int \frac{1}{0.435N-0.00029N^2}dN =\int dt\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$t=2.29885\ln(N)-2.29885\ln(1500-N)+C$$
$-----$
$$t=2.29885\ln(N)-2.29885\ln(1500-N)+C\Longrightarrow$$
$$0=2.29885\ln(200)-2.29885\ln(1500-200)+C\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$0=2.29885\ln(200)-2.29885\ln(1300)+C\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$0=C-0.649008\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$C=0.649008$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

You need to figure out what $N(t)$ is (solve the differential equation). You can separate your varibales to get:

$$\frac{dN}{0,00029N\cdot(1500-N)}=dt$$

Integrate both sides:

$$\int\frac{dN}{0,00029N\cdot(1500-N)}=\int dt \iff 2,29885\ln(N)-2,29885\ln(1500-N)=t+C$$

Now try to solve for $N$